# XSL Position doesn't count correctly

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've been trying a couple of days to resolve this XML transform problem.
I need to add to the XML tags the "identifier" attribute with the sequential number via the XSLT file.
I need to specify that the XSLT version is the 1.0.
P.S. The code worked previously on Internet Explorer but the transform was inovked via JavaScript, thing that I cannot do now because of the newer browser support necessity. For anyone asking, that's a very old piece of code that the client don't want to change.
I also tried to invoke the script via external file but that didn't work either.

That's the XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0" > 
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="identifier">
        <xsl:value-of select = "position()" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There you have the XML instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <topic codice="02220020070748129" coobbligati="0" coobbligatiInfo="Unico Intestatario" status="0" statusWorkInProgress="0" imp1="22285" imp2="0" messaggio="" code="0">
    <fDi>-1</fDi>
    <art>
      <comp message="" code="0" importo="22285" numero="14" flag="0" messageEcc="" codeEcc="0"/>
      <def message="" code="0" importo="0" numero="0" flag="0" messageEcc="" codeEcc="0"/>
      <sel message="" code="0" importo="0" numero="0" flag="0" messageEcc="" codeEcc="0"/>
    </art>
    <datascad>0</datascad>
    <orig>0</orig>
    <sosp>0</sosp>
  </topic>
</root>
```

Now, using the XSLT in the example the result are definetly wrong, counting numbers also for the attributes and tag closing.
An example underneath:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root identifier="1">
  <topic identifier="2" codice="02220020070748129" coobbligati="0" coobbligatiInfo="Unico Intestatario" status="0" statusWorkInProgress="0" imp1="22285" imp2="0" messaggio="" code="0">
    <fDi identifier="11">-1</fDi>
    <art identifier="13">
      <comp identifier="2" message="" code="0" importo="22285" numero="14" flag="0" messageEcc="" codeEcc="0"/>
      <def identifier="4" message="" code="0" importo="0" numero="0" flag="0" messageEcc="" codeEcc="0"/>
      <sel identifier="6" message="" code="0" importo="0" numero="0" flag="0" messageEcc="" codeEcc="0"/>
    </art>
    <datascad identifier="15">0</datascad>
    <orig identifier="17">0</orig>
    <sosp identifier="19">0</sosp>
  </topic>
</root>
```

Instead, the result I need is as it follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <root identifier="1">
    <topic identifier="2" codice="02220020070748129" coobbligati="0" coobbligatiInfo="Unico Intestatario" status="0" statusWorkInProgress="0" imp1="22285" imp2="0" messaggio="" code="0">
      <fDi identifier="3">-1</fDi>
      <art identifier="4">
      <comp identifier="5" message="" code="0" importo="22285" numero="14" flag="0" messageEcc="" codeEcc="0"/>
      <def identifier="6" message="" code="0" importo="0" numero="0" flag="0" messageEcc="" codeEcc="0"/>
      <sel identifier="7" message="" code="0" importo="0" numero="0" flag="0" messageEcc="" codeEcc="0"/>
    </art>
    <datascad identifier="8">0</datascad>
    <orig identifier="9">0</orig>
    <sosp identifier="10">0</sosp>
  </topic>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance for every contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach has two problems:

1. You are assigning an identifier to every **node** (element, attribute, text) in the XML document);
2. The `position(`) function works in the current context, not in the entire  XML document.

I guess you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="identifier">
            <xsl:number count="*" level="any"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hello there! It actually worked! Many thanks for your instant reply. I actually forgot to specify tho, that I need to start counting by 0 and not by 1. Is there any optional config that I can throw it in? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're limited to XSLT 1.0 then put the number in a variable first Then subtract 1 from the variable.

Comment: Ok, done! It works with the following XLST:
` <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:attribute name="identifier">
    <xsl:variable name="id">
     <xsl:number count="*" level="any" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$id - 1" />
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet> `
Thanks again!

Comment: As regards your headline question, `position()` is behaving perfectly correctly, you have just misunderstood how it works. You might find that debugging is easier if you start by assuming the software is right and you are wrong until proven otherwise.